# Fetching row of a table and moving across column of another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table like this with single column,

```
Names 
------
A
B
C
D
E
```

Take each record from table and check previous and next value and put it across new table.
Print 'null' if no previous or next value exists with column name as prev_name,current_name,next

```
Prev_name| Current name| next
-----------------------------
NULL     | A           |B
A        | B           |C 
B        | C           |D 
C        | D           |E 
D        | E           |NULL
```

I am learning SQL and googled to find something which might help solve this but couldn't.

Any help will be great!

Comment: Hint: Use RANK or ROWNUM to find the rows neighboring the row you're looking at.

Answer (score 2):

See this link in fiddle, [Query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2763/17). But NULLS are considered as spaces and omitted in string concatenation.

Please use this query

```
  SELECT LAG(NAMES) OVER(ORDER BY NAMES) AS PREV_NM,  NAMES,
  LEAD(NAMES) OVER(ORDER BY NAMES) AS NEXT_NM
  FROM SAMPLE
```

Fiddle link is changed.

Comment: i was expecting a new table structure with column names prev_name,current_name, next having rows null,a,b,c,d etc .. like what is in the output

Comment: what if the column has records with two entrie 'abb' and 'aaa'. If so, then order by will treat it alphabetical know?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand you said. Can you please explain or edit your question